# Json.Net throwing strange error in Xamarin/MonoTouch Shared Library

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, json.net, portable-class-library

I am creating a generic repository in a Shared Library project in a Xamarin/Monotouch solution. The repository connects to a REST service over http and receives json. I use json.net to deserialize my incoming json. I have the following method in my repo:

```
    public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        List<T> result = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseApiString + _resourceName);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json); //this is where the trouble starts
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I call

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
```

I get the following error:

Could not load type 'System.EmptyArray`1[Reflect.Business.Review]' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

I initially wanted to use RestSharp.Shared (which uses json.net under the covers) so I could use the RestSharp api. This throws the exact same error.

So, do you have any ideas on what is keeping json.net to work nicely in a xamarin shared library project? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you use Json.Net? Do you use nuget package? Can you share your source code?

Comment: I figured it out. The assembly containing the type of one of the sub-sub-sub fields of the model I was trying to deserialized was not referenced in the project, causing the error. Thanks anyway!